# Is the norm on a Hilbert space always finite?

Tags: normed-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $x \in H$ then does it follow that $||x|| < \infty$?

Comment: depends on what you mean by the norm.  for instance $\ell^2$ is the space of sequences $a=(a_n)$, $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ with $||a||:=\sqrt{\sum_n|a_n|^2}<\infty$.

Comment: $||x||^2=<x,x>$, im not looking for a particular hilbert space, but rather i want to know if this is true for any hilbert space

Comment: every (infinite dimensional) seperable hilbert space is isomorphic to $\ell^2$.  the sequence is just the coefficients of some orthonormal basis.

Comment: @yoyo We don't really need separability here. Every Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ has an orthonormal basis $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$. There is a unitary map:  $\mathcal H\to l^2(A)$ defined by $\mathcal H\ni x\mapsto \hat x\in l^2(A)$ with the $\alpha$'s coordinate of $\hat x$ is $\hat x(\alpha)=\langle x,e_\alpha\rangle$. The linearity is easy to check. Isometry follows from Parseval's identity. And isometry also implies injection. It remains to show it is surjective. Note that every square summable sequence naturally corresponds to a Cauchy sequence in $\mathcal H$ by Pythagorean theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer (with some extra text to fill it out): Yes.

:)

Comment: Can you please clarify why this answer is correct?

Answer (score 19):

On any real or complex vector space $X$ for which a norm $\|\cdot\|$ is defined, part of the definition is that $\|x\|$ is a real number for each $x\in X$.  The norm on a real or complex inner product space $H$ fits into this context, because part of the definition of the inner product is that $\langle x,y\rangle$ is a real or complex number for each $x$ and $y$ in $H$, and that $\langle x,x\rangle$ is nonnegative for each $x\in H$, and hence $\langle x,x\rangle$ is a nonnegative real number (excluding the possibility of $\langle x,x\rangle=\infty$).

In some contexts there is notational abuse of $\|\cdot\|$, which may be the source of the question here.  For example, suppose that $\mu$ is a positive measure on $X$, and $1\leq p\lt \infty$.  Some authors will say that for a measurable real or complex-valued function $f$ on $X$, $\|f\|_p$ is defined to be the $p^\text{th}$ root of $\int_X |f|^pd\mu$, before defining $L^p(\mu)$ to be the set of such $f$ for which $\|f\|_p$ is finite.  With this convention, $\|\cdot\|_p$ is a norm *when restricted to $L^p(\mu)$*, but the extended notation allows $\|f\|_p=\infty$ to also be a meaningful statement; it is equivalent to saying that $f$ is not in $L^p(\mu)$.  So for example, $\|f\|_2$ can be infinite for some measurable $f$, but $\|\cdot\|_2$ is a norm on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mu)$, meaning in part that $\|f\|_2$ is a nonnegative real number for all $f\in L^2(\mu)$.

Comment: Can you please clarify why we need to exclude the possibility of $\langle x,x\rangle=\infty$ ?

Comment: @texmex: it's a consequence of the definition of the inner product, its values are complex numbers (or real numbers in the real case) unless you are using some nonstandard definition in which case it would hopefully be called out in context.