# Rudin RCA Theorem 4.17 Questions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

Please note I have two questions regarding Rudin RCA 4.17.
I have consulted the following related questions and these are follow up questions based on the comments from these questions:

1. [Questions in the Proof of Riesz-Fischer Theorem and Bessel's Inequality (Rudin's RCA)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164763/questions-in-the-proof-of-riesz-fischer-theorem-and-bessels-inequality-rudins)
2. [Is the norm on a Hilbert space always finite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/is-the-norm-on-a-hilbert-space-always-finite?noredirect=1&lq=1)

a) In RCA Definition 4.13: The definition of $\hat{x}$ is given as a
complex function defined on the index set $A$ for every $x\in H$
such that $\hat{x}\left(\alpha\right)=\left(x,u\alpha\right)$. How
are we to interpret this definition of $\hat{x}$ as used in Theorem
4.17. Specifically referring to the third part of the question from
the linked question 1, (How does Theorem 4.14(a) show that $f$ is an isometry of $P$ onto the dense subspace of $\ell^2(A)$ consisting of those functions whose support is a finite subset of $A$?):
We have to show that $\left\Vert y_{1}-y_{2}\right\Vert =\left\Vert \hat{y}_{1}-\hat{y}_{2}\right\Vert $ where
$y_{1},y_{2}\in H$. We can take $y_{1},y_{2}\in P$ or as linear
combinations of the orthonormal vectors. But what about $\hat{y_{1}},\hat{y}_{2}$? How can we represent them?

[image]

b) Can you please clarify why $\left\Vert x\right\Vert ^{2}<\infty$?  I am unsure how the definitions given in Rudin RCA regarding a Norm restrict it to be a finite value.
The following picture shows the definition of Norm from 4.1, which I think is relevant. Am happy to add the definition of Lp-Norm from chapter 3 if that is needed as well.
[image]

Please let me know if you need any additional clarifications.

Regarding the comments about complex numbers and infinity ($\infty$) which mention that $\infty$ is not a complex number.
Thanks for pointing this out. While this seems like a reasonable assumption to make on which the definition of norm can be based. I am not entirely sure this follows from what is given in Rudin RCA.

We can infer this based on the definition of a simple function given in Chapter 1 (1.16): A simple function is a complex function from whose range we explicitly exclude infinity ($\infty$). This means that a not simple complex function, which maps to the complex plane, can include infinity.
Perhaps there is something I am overlooking. Can you please point out or clarify?

[image]

Comment: $\infty$ is not a real number or  a complex number. So $(x,x)$ cannot be $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks, So we exclude the extended reals from the definition of a Norm.

Comment: Rudin clearly says that $(x,y)$ is a  complex number.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thanks for pointing this out. While this seems like a reasonable assumption to make on which the definition of norm can be based. I am not entirely sure this follows from what is given in Rudin RCA. Please see the portion I added to the question. From the definition of a simple function, which excludes $\infty$ we can infer that a not simple complex function can include $\infty$. Perhaps there is something I am overlooking. Can you please point out or clarify?